# Wordpress Settings Page

Tags: wordpress, settings

In wordpress backend, under Settings > Reading, I'd like to expand the option to chose what the front page is set to. Currently there are only two options, Blogs Pages and a static page. I will have a series of about 8 different category posts. Is there a way to show or choose a category post (eg A, B, C) to be the homepage?

Comment: Use a query to populate a page with a specific category and make that page the front page.

Comment: yeah, I can do that, but I need the user to be able to change which category is set to home page depending. So figured it would be easiest to have the options show up on the settings dropdown

Comment: If it were me and I wanted to give users that control I would set up ACF and use an options page with a relationship object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, create a custom template specifically for this page. Then, in the Admin Panel, create a page and assign it that template. Your final step would be to go in under Settings > Reading and assign that page as your home page.

Comment: sho there is no way to pull in already existing archive pages?

Comment: If you have one written already that matches the structure/layout you want, then you can use that. Otherwise you will need to create a new php template file for your theme. That is the best option honestly because then you have 100% control over structure and styling.

Comment: When you create the page in the Admin Panel, enter in its name "Home" and nothing else. Then publish it. Then select it in Settings > Reading.